# Error creating pytheapp for Ethereum on OSX

Tags: python, json-rpc, ethereum

I am trying to install pyethapp on OSX but get an error right at the end ""python setup.py egg_info"". Any suggestions?

```
  c233:json-server-api justinstaines$ pip install pyethapp
Collecting pyethapp
  Downloading pyethapp-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (334kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting statistics (from pyethapp)........

Collecting secp256k1 (from ethereum>=1.3.5->pyethapp)
  Downloading secp256k1-0.12.1.tar.gz (144kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 2.3MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Your setuptools version (1.1.6) is too old to correctly install this package. Please upgrade to a newer version (>= 3.3).




    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rb/ydgvprfj6yg5q180740g1lpm0000gn/T/pip-build-KDbJvF/secp256k1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh just realised

Your setuptools version (1.1.6) is too old to correctly install this package. Please upgrade to a newer version (>= 3.3).